# Unit testing Java 2.x Spec EJB in 2015

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb-2.x

I have a legacy application that is quite old.  I have no ability to modernize this application to 3.1 spec EJBs, or really any other holistic API changes.

The application is currently running on a version 7 JDK, on IBM Websphere 8.5.  I use RAD 8.5 as my IDE.

I want to unit test some of my EJB/Server Side code.  All the examples from the first 5 or so google search pages for this kind of testing are from the mid 2000's using Jakarta Cactus, which is a deprecated product.

I don't know if I can do this, but I am trying to use the Embeddable EJB container in My JUnit test class to do this, but I get a "Provider error. No provider definition found" error when I attempt to instantiate the container.

I have no real idea what I am doing here, so I am just trying things and trying to figure it out. If anyone has any suggestions or help, I'd be glad to hear them.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "unit testing"? I find that phrase can mean radically different things to different developers. For example, my stock answer for these sorts of questions is that if you're using a good mocking framework, you shouldn't care about EJB containers etc, since you should only be testing the business logic internal to your EJB. But maybe that's not what you're doing?

Comment: Sure thing. I am trying to simply test one method inside a server side object.   The server side object is basically instantiated by a "factory" class.  The EJB I am trying to use, is like a "global Navigation for my application" Session EJB, but if I can call it, pass it a database ID value, it should be able to run through like 8 other classes from my application to end up giving me an object of the type that contains the method I want to test.

Comment: Have a look at [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/)